# While loop is blocking callback function

Tags: ros2, callback, rclpy

My goal is to stop while loop if return value from callback function  ui_listener_callback will return False (stop) value

```
class AxisControlNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('axis_control_node')
        self.callback_group = ReentrantCallbackGroup()
        self.ui_listener = self.create_subscription(AxisControl,
                                                    '/middleware/control/axis',
                                                    callback=self.ui_listener_callback,
                                                    qos_profile=10,
                                                    callback_group=self.callback_group)
        self.current_position_listener = self.create_subscription(String,
                                                                  'current_position_topic',
                                                                  self.current_position_callback,
                                                                  10)
        self.current_position = '7653POS000+000.000+000.000+000.000+000.000+000.000+000.000+000.000+000.000'
        self.axis_command_publisher = self.create_publisher(String,
                                                            'axis_command_topic',
                                                            10)

    def ui_listener_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info(f'data received: axis {msg.axis}, direction {msg.direction}, move {msg.move}')
        if msg.move:
            self.start_move(msg.axis, msg.direction, msg.move)
        else:
            self.stop_move()
        return move

    def current_position_callback(self, msg):
        self.current_position = msg.data

    @snoop
    def start_move(self, axis, direction, move):
        axis_command = String()
        axis_pos = float(self.current_position[10 + 8 * (axis - 1):10 + 8 * axis])
        axis_step = 0.5
        while (axis_pos < 170.000) and (axis_pos > -170.000):
            new_pos = self.current_position
           ....
            self.axis_command_publisher.publish(axis_command)
```

I have already tried to add value from callback function to constructor and add it to while loop conditions:

```
self.last_move = True
while (axis_pos < 170.000) and (axis_pos > -170.000) and move:
```

But it didnt work. ROS2 Humble, Ubuntu 22.04, rclpy

Comment: Two suggestions to allow people to provide better help: include all the code you're having issues with(there is no while loop in the code you posted, the call to the constructor not shown, the method of spin not included, etc), and explain what leads to your thinking that the while loop is blocking the callback function. What testing have you done that makes you think this?